# Why does my script for a Chrome extension that is meant to get the current url not work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, permissions

I got a script from Stack Overflow for getting the current Chrome tab, but every time I try to run it, this error shows up in Google Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
Context

https://www.youtube.com/
Stack Trace

**chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {**
    let url = tabs[0].url;
    // use `url` here inside the callback because it's asynchronous!
});
```

The code in bold is the highlighted code in the error. I have tried to replace `currentWindow` with `lastFocusedWindow`, but that did nothing. The permissions are all correct, and I even added extra permissions that I do not need, as shown here:

```
"permissions": [ 
    "tabs", 
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab" ]
```

I only need `tabs` and `<all_urls>` for my script, but I have `activeTab` just in case. What is the problem here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The error message says `chrome.tabs` is undefined which can happen only if you try to use it in a content script or in a normal page script. Content scripts can't use most of chrome API. You don't need chrome.tabs to get the current URL in a content script anyway: simply use `location.href`. Each matching tab runs an instance of the content script so don't confuse it with a background script which runs in a separate hidden background page.

Comment: @wOxxOm How do I implement `location.href` into my script?

Comment: It's a standard feature, no need to implement it, just use it, examples are easy to find.

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry I was using really complicated Google keywords then when you google location.href it is really easy.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do it.

1. calling `getCurrent()`. More details here on which page you should execute the script -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/getCurrent

   chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function callback)
2. If you want the current URL on click of browser action then.

   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( activeTab =>  {
       console.log(activeTab);
   });

Comment: Content scripts can't use chrome.tabs or chrome.browserAction, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).